# AWS EC2 userdata to start tomcat when EC2 started

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have AMI(It contains java,tomcat and tomcat installed and env varibles path set JAVA_HOME and CATALINA_HOME, webapp have myapplication) while creating EC2 from AMI , i have configured userdata as following

```
<script>
C:\MySoftwares\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\bin\startup.bat
</script>
<persist>true</persist>
```

when ever EC2 created and started from AMI, I was expecting tomcat server will start, but it is not startiing, I have to manually and open cmd prompt and type

```
c:\>startup.bat
```

then server is started.

My question is , why tomcat is not started even if i added in userdata.

Comment: Check the Instance Console Output for any errors. Add echo statements before and after calling startup.bat so that you can verify that that your userdata is actually executing. That aside, you should probably install Tomcat as an auto-started Windows service rather than rely on a one-time (only at launch) batch file.

Comment: @jarmod I install Tomcat as an auto-started Windows service, it works fine.
I will check console logs, does the script correct ?

Comment: Sorry, I’m not sure what your question is.

Comment: My question was, is this script <script>
C:\MySoftwares\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\bin\startup.bat
</script>
<persist>true</persist>  in userdata correct ?

Comment: It seems reasonable in that it's between script tags and you've indicated persist=true so that it runs every time you reboot or start the instance. I have no idea if there is actually a startup.bat at that location, of course. If you're trying to debug this, why don't you add echo statements around the call to startup.bat and add echo statements inside startup.bat (preferably echo to stdout *and* echo to a local file that you can review afterwards).